# Using a Layer within Lambdas failed to import module named 'x' - (This module is in my Layer)

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, seleniumwire

I've built a Layer for Lambdas using instructions [here](https://bluegrid.io/build-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-runtime/). The package I'm trying to add is: selenium-wire

When I test my Lambda I get this:

[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'seleniumwire'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Any Ideas?

I've tried including the package contents of selenium-wire within the folder which imports seleniumwire, but gives me an error pointing to invalid ELF which is what led me to use the instructions linked above.

Comment: Do you use Mac OS on M1 CPU?

Comment: @Corralien yes I do.

Comment: So it's not possible to work as there are native libraries to compile. AWS Lambda works only on x86 archicture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[...]$ git clone https://github.com/bluegridio/build-lambda-layer.git
[...]$ cd build-lambda-layer
[...]$ ./build-lambda-layer.sh selenium-wire
```

Check:

```
[...]$ unzip -l selenium-wire.zip python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seleniumwire/

Archive:  selenium-wire.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2023-01-31 08:18   python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seleniumwire/
---------                     -------
        0                     1 file
```

Comment: I tried this and got same result: @Corralien